# Replace is not working for weird character

Tags: sql-server, oracle, replace, plsql

I use `UPDATE a SET GR_P = REPLACE(GR_P,'','') FROM mytable a` to replace things.

But replace function is not working for below charter:

[image]

In Query analyzer it works but when I used SSIS Execute SQL task or OLEDB Source then it is giving me error:

> No Connection manager is specified.

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: not sure. This string character from RTF file.

Comment: But what programming language is it? Is this MySQL?

Comment: PL/SQL. We are using sql server 2014.

Comment: `PL/SQL` is Oracle. `SQL Server` is Microsoft. If you're using the procedural extension of SQL Server, that's `t-sql`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Toad against Oracle (since that's one of your tags), I issued this (pressing ALT-12 to get the female symbol) and got 191 as a result. note selecting it back using `CHR(191)` shows an upside-down question mark though.

```
select ascii('♀') from dual;
```

Given that, this worked but it's Oracle syntax, your mileage may vary.

```
UPDATE mytable SET GR_P = REPLACE(GR_P, CHR(191));
```

Note if it does not work, that symbol could be for another control character.  You may need to use a regular expression to eliminate all characters not in a-zA-Z0-9, etc.  I suspect you'll need to update your tags to get a more accurate answer.

Maybe this info will help anyway. Please post back what you find out.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I wrote procedure (with Replace Code) and called it in Execute SQL Task. That worked!! OLEDB Connection manager doesn't understand that character..

Comment: If it worked for you please mark it as accepted for future searchers.  Thanks, glad it helped.